# Not able to create a proper Firewall rule on google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I only want to allow access to my db server from my instance group on google cloud so i wont able to add firewall rule for that. If any one knows please help me.

db server is host on google compute engine out of instance group.

Comment: Are you using gcloud, UI or API to create the rule?

Comment: @Ryank using gcloud ui